# object deconstruction with default deconstructed value javascript

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I'm looking for a concise and efficient way to achieve the following:

Whether property exists in `data` or not, override it if exists in `overriders`

```
fn(data = {}, overriders = {}) {

  data = {property: 2};

  let { property = data.property } = overriders;
  console.log(property); // = 2
}
```

It works and it's quite alright

Is there a better way? I was hoping for something like this:

```
fn(data = {}, overriders = {}) {

  data = {property: 2};
  overriders = {property: 9}

  let { property } = data || overriders;
  console.log(property); // = 9
}
```

(I know it resembles `fallback` but I was looking for something close to it syntaxwise)

Comment: `Object.assign`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function fn(data = {property: 2}, overriders = {property: 9}) {
  let { property } = {...data, ...overriders};
  console.log(property); // = 9
}

fn();
```

Comment: Both yours and @Crisoforo Gaspar's answers hit the charts but yours is even more concise to the usecase therefore marked

Answer (score 2):

You can use object destructuring.

```
function changeData( data = {}, overrides = {} ) {
  return { ...overrides, ...data }; 
}

console.log( changeData( { property: 2 }, { property: 9, a: 1, b: 2 }) ) ;
```

[Additional Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)